# NodeJS: Typescript compiler runs out of memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, memory, heap-memory

I'm trying to run a node server on a free AWS EC 2 instance.
Locally I can build and run my server, on AWS it keeps crashing, though.

I run `$ npm run build`

Error message:

```
findus    | <--- Last few GCs --->
findus    | 
findus    | [18:0x55b075815d80]    19411 ms: Mark-sweep 487.8 (491.0) -> 487.2 (491.2) MB, 721.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.110, current mu = 0.019) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
findus    | [18:0x55b075815d80]    20137 ms: Mark-sweep 487.9 (491.2) -> 487.3 (491.5) MB, 723.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.060, current mu = 0.004) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
findus    | 
findus    | 
findus    | <--- JS stacktrace --->
findus    | 
findus    | ==== JS stack trace =========================================
findus    | 
findus    |     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x55b070dd2eb9]
findus    | Security context: 0x24cb05dc0921 <JSObject>
findus    |     1: setParentPointers(aka setParentPointers) [0x34cec2b85941] [/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:~27701] [pc=0x770d079eae0](this=0x0bad1a5804b9 <undefined>,0x3d868a943641 <Node map = 0x1c6b95afc031>,0x3d868a944181 <Node map = 0x1c6b95af7a81>)
findus    |     2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x33ec79ae66b1] [/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:27703]...
findus    | 
findus    | FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
findus    | 
findus    | Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200502.192713.18.0.001.json
findus    | Node.js report completed
findus    | Aborted (core dumped)
findus    | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
findus    | npm ERR! errno 134
findus    | npm ERR! findus-backend@1.0.0 prod: `tsc && node build/index.js`
findus    | npm ERR! Exit status 134
findus    | npm ERR! 
findus    | npm ERR! Failed at the findus-backend@1.0.0 prod script.
findus    | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
findus    | 
findus    | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
findus    | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-02T19_27_18_024Z-debug.log
findus exited with code 134
```

Is there a way to run `tsc` on servers with low memory?

My package.json

```
{
    "name": "findus-backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "dev": "nodemon source/index.ts",
        "prod": "tsc && node build/index.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/cron": "^1.7.1",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
        "@types/mongodb": "^3.3.13",
        "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.34",
        "@types/node": "^12.12.25",
        "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.5",
        "cron": "^1.8.2",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "googleapis": "^47.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "mongoose": "^5.8.1",
        "rss-parser": "^3.7.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
        "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
        "typescript": " 3.3.3"
    }
}
```

Report:

```
{
  "header": {
    "reportVersion": 2,
    "event": "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory",
    "trigger": "FatalError",
    "filename": "report.20200502.194450.30170.0.001.json",
    "dumpEventTime": "2020-05-02T19:44:50Z",
    "dumpEventTimeStamp": "1588448690491",
    "processId": 30170,
    "threadId": null,
    "cwd": "/home/ubuntu/Findus/Backend",
    "commandLine": [
      "node",
      "/home/ubuntu/Findus/Backend/node_modules/.bin/tsc"
    ],
    "nodejsVersion": "v12.16.3",
    "glibcVersionRuntime": "2.27",
    "glibcVersionCompiler": "2.17",
    "wordSize": 64,
    "arch": "x64",
    "platform": "linux",
    "componentVersions": {
      "node": "12.16.3",
      "v8": "7.8.279.23-node.35",
      "uv": "1.34.2",
      "zlib": "1.2.11",
      "brotli": "1.0.7",
      "ares": "1.16.0",
      "modules": "72",
      "nghttp2": "1.40.0",
      "napi": "5",
      "llhttp": "2.0.4",
      "http_parser": "2.9.3",
      "openssl": "1.1.1g",
      "cldr": "36.0",
      "icu": "65.1",
      "tz": "2019c",
      "unicode": "12.1"
    },
    "release": {
      "name": "node",
      "lts": "Erbium",
      "headersUrl": "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3-headers.tar.gz",
      "sourceUrl": "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.3/node-v12.16.3.tar.gz"
    },
    "osName": "Linux",
    "osRelease": "5.3.0-1017-aws",
    "osVersion": "#18~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 8 15:12:16 UTC 2020",
    "osMachine": "x86_64",
    "cpus": [
      {
        "model": "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz",
        "speed": 2400,
        "user": 7780600,
        "nice": 141600,
        "sys": 5849500,
        "idle": 1138420300,
        "irq": 0
      }
    ],
    "networkInterfaces": [
      {
        "name": "lo",
        "internal": true,
        "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "netmask": "255.0.0.0",
        "family": "IPv4"
      },
      {
        "name": "eth0",
        "internal": false,
        "mac": "0a:85:22:ae:d6:7a",
        "address": "172.31.45.156",
        "netmask": "255.255.240.0",
        "family": "IPv4"
      },
      {
        "name": "lo",
        "internal": true,
        "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
        "address": "::1",
        "netmask": "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff",
        "family": "IPv6",
        "scopeid": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "eth0",
        "internal": false,
        "mac": "0a:85:22:ae:d6:7a",
        "address": "fe80::885:22ff:feae:d67a",
        "netmask": "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::",
        "family": "IPv6",
        "scopeid": 2
      }
    ],
    "host": "ip-172-31-45-156"
  },
  "javascriptStack": {
    "message": "No stack.",
    "stack": [
      "Unavailable."
    ]
  },
  "nativeStack": [
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000b46955",
      "symbol": "report::TriggerNodeReport(v8::Isolate*, node::Environment*, char const*, char const*, std::string const&, v8::Local<v8::String>) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000a09c8f",
      "symbol": "node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000b7d71e",
      "symbol": "v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000b7da99",
      "symbol": "v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000d2a1f5",
      "symbol": " [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000d2a886",
      "symbol": "v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000d37105",
      "symbol": "v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000d37fb5",
      "symbol": "v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000d3aa6c",
      "symbol": "v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x0000000000d0163b",
      "symbol": "v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x000000000104300e",
      "symbol": "v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]"
    },
    {
      "pc": "0x00000000013c5b79",
      "symbol": " [node]"
    }
  ],
  "javascriptHeap": {
    "totalMemory": 515842048,
    "totalCommittedMemory": 514610432,
    "usedMemory": 510824048,
    "availableMemory": 11324416,
    "memoryLimit": 525336576,
    "heapSpaces": {
      "read_only_space": {
        "memorySize": 262144,
        "committedMemory": 33088,
        "capacity": 32808,
        "used": 32808,
        "available": 0
      },
      "new_space": {
        "memorySize": 2097152,
        "committedMemory": 1357744,
        "capacity": 1047456,
        "used": 340552,
        "available": 706904
      },
      "old_space": {
        "memorySize": 469377024,
        "committedMemory": 469280296,
        "capacity": 467181736,
        "used": 467106208,
        "available": 75528
      },
      "code_space": {
        "memorySize": 1216512,
        "committedMemory": 1059392,
        "capacity": 925664,
        "used": 925664,
        "available": 0
      },
      "map_space": {
        "memorySize": 528384,
        "committedMemory": 519080,
        "capacity": 326640,
        "used": 326640,
        "available": 0
      },
      "large_object_space": {
        "memorySize": 42311680,
        "committedMemory": 42311680,
        "capacity": 42089392,
        "used": 42089392,
        "available": 0
      },
      "code_large_object_space": {
        "memorySize": 49152,
        "committedMemory": 49152,
        "capacity": 2784,
        "used": 2784,
        "available": 0
      },
      "new_large_object_space": {
        "memorySize": 0,
        "committedMemory": 0,
        "capacity": 1047456,
        "used": 0,
        "available": 1047456
      }
    }
  },
  "resourceUsage": {
    "userCpuSeconds": 19.9575,
    "kernelCpuSeconds": 0.539212,
    "cpuConsumptionPercent": 97.6036,
    "maxRss": 580542464,
    "pageFaults": {
      "IORequired": 1,
      "IONotRequired": 149827
    },
    "fsActivity": {
      "reads": 92264,
      "writes": 0
    }
  },
  "uvthreadResourceUsage": {
    "userCpuSeconds": 9.14098,
    "kernelCpuSeconds": 0.234258,
    "cpuConsumptionPercent": 44.644,
    "fsActivity": {
      "reads": 92008,
      "writes": 0
    }
  },
  "libuv": [
  ],
  "workers": [
  ],
  "environmentVariables": {
    "LESSOPEN": "| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s",
    "npm_package_devDependencies_ts_node": "^8.6.2",
    "npm_config_cache_lock_stale": "60000",
    "npm_config_ham_it_up": "",
    "npm_config_legacy_bundling": "",
    "npm_config_sign_git_tag": "",
    "MAIL": "/var/mail/ubuntu",
    "USER": "ubuntu",
    "SSH_CLIENT": "5.231.149.16 39054 22",
    "LC_TIME": "C.UTF-8",
    "npm_config_user_agent": "npm/6.14.4 node/v12.16.3 linux x64",
    "npm_config_always_auth": "",
    "npm_config_bin_links": "true",
    "npm_config_key": "",
    "npm_package_dependencies__types_lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "npm_package_devDependencies_nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "npm_config_allow_same_version": "",
    "npm_config_description": "true",
    "npm_config_fetch_retries": "2",
    "npm_config_heading": "npm",
    "npm_config_if_present": "",
    "npm_config_init_version": "1.0.0",
    "npm_config_user": "",
    "npm_node_execpath": "/usr/bin/node",
    "SHLVL": "1",
    "npm_config_prefer_online": "",
    "npm_config_noproxy": "",
    "HOME": "/home/ubuntu",
    "OLDPWD": "/home/ubuntu/Findus",
    "npm_package_dependencies__types_mongoose": "^5.5.34",
    "npm_config_force": "",
    "SSH_TTY": "/dev/pts/0",
    "npm_config_only": "",
    "npm_config_read_only": "",
    "npm_config_cache_min": "10",
    "npm_config_init_license": "ISC",
    "npm_config_editor": "vi",
    "npm_config_rollback": "true",
    "npm_config_tag_version_prefix": "v",
    "LC_MONETARY": "C.UTF-8",
    "npm_config_cache_max": "Infinity",
    "npm_config_timing": "",
    "npm_config_userconfig": "/home/ubuntu/.npmrc",
    "npm_config_engine_strict": "",
    "npm_config_init_author_name": "",
    "npm_config_init_author_url": "",
    "npm_config_preid": "",
    "npm_config_tmp": "/tmp",
    "npm_package_description": "",
    "npm_package_devDependencies_typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "npm_config_depth": "Infinity",
    "npm_config_package_lock_only": "",
    "npm_config_save_dev": "",
    "npm_config_usage": "",
    "npm_config_metrics_registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "npm_config_cafile": "",
    "npm_config_otp": "",
    "npm_config_package_lock": "true",
    "npm_config_progress": "true",
    "npm_config_https_proxy": "",
    "npm_config_save_prod": "",
    "npm_package_scripts_dev": "nodemon source/index.ts",
    "npm_config_audit": "true",
    "npm_config_cidr": "",
    "npm_config_onload_script": "",
    "npm_config_sso_type": "oauth",
    "LOGNAME": "ubuntu",
    "npm_package_scripts_prod": "tsc && node build/index.js",
    "npm_config_rebuild_bundle": "true",
    "npm_config_save_bundle": "",
    "npm_config_shell": "/bin/bash",
    "_": "/usr/bin/npm",
    "npm_package_dependencies__types_xml2js": "^0.4.5",
    "npm_package_dependencies_express": "^4.17.1",
    "npm_config_dry_run": "",
    "npm_config_format_package_lock": "true",
    "npm_config_prefix": "/usr",
    "npm_config_scope": "",
    "npm_config_browser": "",
    "npm_config_cache_lock_wait": "10000",
    "npm_config_ignore_prepublish": "",
    "npm_config_registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "npm_config_save_optional": "",
    "npm_config_searchopts": "",
    "npm_config_versions": "",
    "XDG_SESSION_ID": "43",
    "TERM": "xterm-256color",
    "npm_package_dependencies_rss_parser": "^3.7.3",
    "npm_config_cache": "/home/ubuntu/.npm",
    "npm_config_proxy": "",
    "npm_config_send_metrics": "",
    "npm_config_global_style": "",
    "npm_config_ignore_scripts": "",
    "npm_config_version": "",
    "npm_config_local_address": "",
    "npm_config_viewer": "man",
    "npm_config_node_gyp": "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js",
    "PATH": "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ubuntu/Findus/Backend/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin",
    "npm_package_name": "findus-backend",
    "npm_config_audit_level": "low",
    "npm_config_prefer_offline": "",
    "NODE": "/usr/bin/node",
    "LC_ADDRESS": "C.UTF-8",
    "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR": "/run/user/1000",
    "npm_config_color": "true",
    "npm_config_sign_git_commit": "",
    "npm_package_dependencies_cron": "^1.8.2",
    "npm_config_fetch_retry_mintimeout": "10000",
    "npm_config_maxsockets": "50",
    "npm_config_offline": "",
    "npm_config_sso_poll_frequency": "500",
    "LANG": "C.UTF-8",
    "LC_TELEPHONE": "C.UTF-8",
    "npm_config_umask": "0002",
    "LS_COLORS": "rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:",
    "npm_package_main": "index.js",
    "npm_package_dependencies__types_node": "^12.12.25",
    "npm_config_fund": "true",
    "npm_config_fetch_retry_maxtimeout": "60000",
    "npm_config_loglevel": "notice",
    "npm_config_logs_max": "10",
    "npm_config_message": "%s",
    "npm_lifecycle_script": "tsc",
    "npm_config_ca": "",
    "npm_config_cert": "",
    "npm_config_global": "",
    "npm_config_link": "",
    "LC_NAME": "C.UTF-8",
    "SHELL": "/bin/bash",
    "npm_package_version": "1.0.0",
    "npm_config_access": "",
    "npm_config_also": "",
    "npm_config_save": "true",
    "npm_config_unicode": "true",
    "npm_lifecycle_event": "build",
    "npm_package_scripts_build": "tsc",
    "npm_config_argv": "{\"remain\":[],\"cooked\":[\"run\",\"build\"],\"original\":[\"run\",\"build\"]}",
    "npm_config_before": "",
    "npm_config_long": "",
    "npm_config_production": "",
    "npm_config_searchlimit": "20",
    "npm_config_unsafe_perm": "true",
    "npm_config_update_notifier": "true",
    "LESSCLOSE": "/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s",
    "npm_package_author": "",
    "npm_package_dependencies_lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "npm_config_auth_type": "legacy",
    "npm_config_node_version": "12.16.3",
    "npm_config_tag": "latest",
    "LC_MEASUREMENT": "C.UTF-8",
    "npm_package_dependencies__types_express": "^4.17.2",
    "npm_config_git_tag_version": "true",
    "npm_config_commit_hooks": "true",
    "npm_config_script_shell": "",
    "npm_config_shrinkwrap": "true",
    "LC_IDENTIFICATION": "C.UTF-8",
    "npm_package_license": "ISC",
    "npm_package_dependencies_googleapis": "^47.0.0",
    "npm_package_dependencies_mongoose": "^5.8.1",
    "npm_config_fetch_retry_factor": "10",
    "npm_config_save_exact": "",
    "npm_config_strict_ssl": "true",
    "npm_config_dev": "",
    "npm_config_globalconfig": "/usr/etc/npmrc",
    "npm_config_init_module": "/home/ubuntu/.npm-init.js",
    "npm_config_parseable": "",
    "PWD": "/home/ubuntu/Findus/Backend",
    "npm_package_dependencies__types_mongodb": "^3.3.13",
    "npm_config_globalignorefile": "/usr/etc/npmignore",
    "npm_execpath": "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js",
    "SSH_CONNECTION": "5.231.149.16 39054 172.31.45.156 22",
    "XDG_DATA_DIRS": "/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop",
    "npm_config_cache_lock_retries": "10",
    "npm_config_searchstaleness": "900",
    "LC_NUMERIC": "C.UTF-8",
    "npm_config_node_options": "",
    "npm_config_save_prefix": "^",
    "npm_config_scripts_prepend_node_path": "warn-only",
    "LC_PAPER": "C.UTF-8",
    "npm_config_group": "1000",
    "npm_config_init_author_email": "",
    "npm_config_searchexclude": "",
    "npm_package_dependencies__types_cron": "^1.7.1",
    "npm_config_git": "git",
    "npm_config_optional": "true",
    "npm_config_json": "",
    "INIT_CWD": "/home/ubuntu/Findus/Backend"
  },
  "userLimits": {
    "core_file_size_blocks": {
      "soft": 0,
      "hard": "unlimited"
    },
    "data_seg_size_kbytes": {
      "soft": "unlimited",
      "hard": "unlimited"
    },
    "file_size_blocks": {
      "soft": "unlimited",
      "hard": "unlimited"
    },
    "max_locked_memory_bytes": {
      "soft": 16777216,
      "hard": 16777216
    },
    "max_memory_size_kbytes": {
      "soft": "unlimited",
      "hard": "unlimited"
    },
    "open_files": {
      "soft": 1048576,
      "hard": 1048576
    },
    "stack_size_bytes": {
      "soft": 8388608,
      "hard": "unlimited"
    },
    "cpu_time_seconds": {
      "soft": "unlimited",
      "hard": "unlimited"
    },
    "max_user_processes": {
      "soft": 3739,
      "hard": 3739
    },
    "virtual_memory_kbytes": {
      "soft": "unlimited",
      "hard": "unlimited"
    }
  },
  "sharedObjects": [
    "linux-vdso.so.1",
    "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2",
    "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6",
    "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6",
    "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1",
    "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0",
    "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6",
    "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using `--max-old-space-size` in `NODE_OPTIONS` worked for me

Add this options in your `package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' ts-node index.ts"
   }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: Try with `--max-old-space-size=16384`

Answer (score -1):

I needed to create a swapfile as per the instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Note that linked content is not considered part of an answer here. And "create a swapfile" seems something of a brief answer. You might want to elaborate, ideally by [edit]ing according to [answer].

Answer (score -4):

In the end I fixed it by using more RAM on my server.

---

In my opinion it is a solution. It didn't work before, now it works. It is just not a software-only solution.

My server had 512MB of ram or something which is very low for our time. Node just needed more to run. Maybe there are different solutions where you can run the required steps on a low-spec environment, but for me this was the easiest fix.

Comment: I have the same problem.. that's not a solution :\

Comment: Really??? F*K TS..

Answer (score -4):

If you are not interested in Typescript type analysis (as when one is not developing but just installing SW), you might disable it with `transpileOnly: true`.

It looks like this in `.tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "transpileOnly": true
    ...
},
```

This solved a similar problem I had while compiling a TS project through Webpack.

Comment: tsconfig.json:3:5 - error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'transpileOnly'.

3     "transpileOnly": true,

Comment: That is only for `ts-node` and `ts-loader`, but it does not work for `tsc`. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29651. Also please downvote this answer, for it is incorrect and misleading and will make people like me lose their time.

Comment: This may be misleading to some but there is some sort of memory leak occurring in one of these apps in the create-react-app and this solution fixed it for me.